# Django Admin: Model Foreignkey has null & blank = True, but using formfield_for_foreignkey in Admin makes it required

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-admin

My model has a ForeignKey with null=True / blank=True, but when I try to alter an object in Django Admin I am using

```
def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'parent_locale':
            return ParentLocaleChoiceField(queryset=models.Locale.objects.all().order_by('display'))
        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

to alter how the data displays there.  But doing this now throws an error when submitting saying the field is required.  How to do I make this field not required when using formfield_for_foreignkey to alter the choice field display?

Comment: Pass `required=False` to the field?

Comment: @IainShelvington Ah, Thanks!  I thought maybe I was having to do some custom Form for it and define the False there. Nope...

ParentLocaleChoiceField(queryset=models.Locale.objects.all().order_by('display'), required=False) did it

Answer (score 0):

Add the required=False on the ParentLocaleChoiceField

```
def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'parent_locale':
            return ParentLocaleChoiceField(queryset=models.Locale.objects.all().order_by('display'), required=False)
        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```